# How should I access class members in beforeExecute and afterExecute hooks in ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable, threadpoolexecutor

I am extending the ThreadPoolExecutor class. Inside it I want to set a member value in the beforeExecute (Thread t, Runnable r) and the afterExecute (Runnable r, Throwable t). I am not sure how to do so. Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you want to access an instance field of your `Runnable` instances.  To access them you will need to downcast the `Runnable` to the actual class of your `Runnable` class, and then access the fields via the downcast reference.  Or better still, make the fields private and access them via getter / setter calls on the reference.

This could be awkward if your `Runnable` is an anonymous inner class.  In that case, you may need to turn it into a named class: either nested, inner or top level.

On the other hand, if you are talking about `static` fields or methods of the `Runnable` implementation class, you can just use them as you would normally ... provided that the access modifiers allow this.

Comment: I ran across you post looking for a solution but this does not work. The Runnable argument to beforeExecute and afterExecute is acutally a java.util.concurrent.FutureTask which cannot be cast to my Runnable implementation. I am using java 7 so I don't know if the ThreadPoolExecutor has been changed since your post. Maybe that is the cause of why it doesn't work.

Comment: I ran into exactly the same issue. I have my own class that implements `Runnable`. I thought that beforeExecute() would be a good point for notifying a listener that my runnable starts now its execution.